# Highlighting extremal values in table when all values are not the same data type

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, highlighting

I have a table generated by pgfplotstable, and would like to highlight the maximum value in each row for a particular number of columns.

Here is a simple, completely made up, example that should illustrate my problem:

```
                                 Car 1    Car 2    Car 3    Car 4
 Engine       Power(bhp)          300      200      350      250
              Torque (Nm)         200      250      120      400
 Dimensions   Wheel base (cm)     250      200      240      220
              Ground clearance    ...
                    ...
```

I'd like to make the maximum value in each row, excluding the first two columns, bold. This is a slight extension of [Highlighting Extremal Values in Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/highlighting-extremal-values-in-table), which has an excellent solution that I am trying to extend. (Unfortunately I can't add a comment to that thread because I have just joined stackexchange).

The code I need from the previous thread is

```
\newcommand{\findmax}[3]{
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{#1}
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/expr={%
        \pgfplotstablerow
    }]{rownumber}\datatable
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#2},sort cmp={float >}]{\sorted}{\datatable}%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{rownumber}\of{\sorted}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro#3{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstableclear{\datatable}
}

\pgfplotstableset{
    highlight row max/.code 2 args={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rowindex{#2-1}
        \pgfplotstabletranspose{\transposed}{#1}
        \findmax{\transposed}{\rowindex}{\maxval}
        \edef\setstyles{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
                every row \rowindex\space column \maxval\noexpand/.style={
                    postproc cell content/.append style={
                        /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\noexpand\bf}{$}
                    },
                }
            }
        }\setstyles
    }
}
```

The table is read in with `\pgfplotstableread{...}\data` and then the above code called using

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    highlight row max ={\data}{1},
    highlight row max ={\data}{2},
    highlight row max ={\data}{3},
    ...
]{\data}
```

If this code is run for my example then it fails because the first two columns are not a float for the comparison. I understand the above code and have tried to extend it but am not an expert at tex.

I have managed to get a non general solution by limiting the columns that are generated by the transpose command:

```
pgfplotstabletranspose[columns={Car 1,Car 2,Car 3,Car 4}]{\transposed}{#1}
```

then the index of the column returned from \findmax just has to be increased to account for the offset.

I would like a more general approach that will work for any table. My current idea is to change the contents of any cell in the transposed table that is not a float to 0. I'm currently unable to find a way to do this.

Comment: Please expand this to a complete, self-contained [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).