# row index of first non-zero element in pgfplotstable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am using the "functions" `\findmin` and `findmax` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34045/18730) quite much to dynamical format and set plots from CSV data I read in.

In the same vein, I want a function `\findFirstNonZeroIndex`, which returns the integer index of the first element which is non-zero in a specified column. Since all my data are non-negative integers, non-zero is equal to being greater than 0.

Since the indices in `pgfplotstable` start with 0, how do I add 1 to this number?

From the [pgfplotstable manuel](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf), the `iflessthan` command seems capable of doing what I want:

```
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#2},sort cmp={
  iflessthan/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{%
    % here comes your code
  }%
}]{\result}{\datatable}
```

Some example data:

```
\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
  x y
  1 0
  2 0
  3 30
  4 0
  5 50
\end{filecontents}
```

If possible, I do only want to use the column =`y`=`index[1]` and get something like `\findFirstNonZeroIndex{\inputtable}{\outputvalue}`. In this example, `\outputvalue` should be 3.

If it is easier, up to now I only use integer values in column `y` sorted ascending. So there would not be a 0 in row x=4.

I just do not know enough on how to get started. Any help would be appreciated.

## Edit

Steven B. Segletes just [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229874/18730) my question with the help of package `readarray`.

Out of curiosity, is there a solution using the pgf framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do this using PGFPlotstable. I defined a macro that takes three arguments: The macro containing the table that was loaded using `\pgfplotstableread`, the name of the column, and the macro that contains the output. Note that PGFPlotstable uses zero based indexing, so if the first non-zero element is in the third row, the output will be `2`. If no non-zero values are found, the output will be `-1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
  x y
  1 0
  2 0
  3 30
  4 0
  5 50
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\findFirstNonZeroIndex[3]{
    \def#3{-1}
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#2}\of{#1}\as\cell{
        \ifnum#3=-1
            \ifnum\cell>0
                \xdef#3{\pgfplotstablerow}
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{table.dat}\datatable
\findFirstNonZeroIndex{\datatable}{y}{\outputvalue}
\outputvalue

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. 
As I understand this approach only works when comparing integers, as I requested (because of \ifnum ?!). How would one modify this solution to compare doubles, i.e. find the first row with double element > 0?

Comment: @MarcoBreitig: Do you have large numbers (greater than 16000)?

Comment: No, between 100 to 3000 elements per column.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig: Sorry, I meant the values of your floats. If they're under 16000 you can simply use `\ifdim\cell pt>0pt`, but if they're larger than that you'll need to use the `fpu` library.

Comment: In the same region, just counting. The double data is in [0,1], building ratios. 
Thx, I just tried it and it works. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The macro `\firstdata{`column`}` will find the first positive entry in the specified column (beginning at row 2, since row 1 is alphabetic).  Once found, it will output the value of column 1 from that row, which, in the data structure, is the datapoint number.

Thus, this MWE outputs the result `3`.

The `readarray` package stores the file in one large `\def`, in this case `\mydata`.  It then creates an array structure, here named `thedata`, by reading `\mydata` as a 2 column array of space-separated values.  Individual cells of the array may be recalled with `\arrayij{thedata}{row}{column}` and compared against `0` to detect positiveness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents,ifthen}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.dat}
  x y
  1 0
  2 0
  3 30
  4 0
  5 50
\end{filecontents*}
\readdef{table.dat}{\mydata}
\readArrayij{\mydata}{thedata}{2}
\newcounter{currentrow}
\def\firstdata#1{%
  \setcounter{currentrow}{1}%
  \whiledo{\value{currentrow}<\thedataROWS}{%
    \stepcounter{currentrow}%
    \ifnum\arrayij{thedata}{\thecurrentrow}{#1}>0
      \arrayij{thedata}{\thecurrentrow}{1}%
      \setcounter{currentrow}{\thedataROWS}%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\firstdata{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx! I see you use the packages `readarray` and `filecontents`. Are they related to pgf or on their own?

Comment: They are on their own.  I wrote the `readarray` package, but don't know a lick about `pgf`.

Comment: @MarcoBreitig I only use `filecontents` as a vehicle to create the data to begin with.  If the data already exists in a separate file, or is placed inside of a `\def` within the document through some other means, the `filecontents` would not be required.

Comment: Ah of course. That is the pitfall if you do not give a MWE yourself. Thank you for pointing this out!